# Opened popup crashes leaflet if keeping two maps in sync

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I have scenario where I need to keep 2 maps in sync in a sense that their center and zoom match one or the other when the map is moved/zoomed. Using the `onViewportChanged` event handler to set the state for the map in parent component. Both maps have markers but for showing different objects depending on the map. App crashes whenever any of the popup has been clicked opened and the map is then moved so that popup is left outside of the current bounding box.
The full stack trace from console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at removeClass (leaflet-src.js:2355)
    at NewClass._onPanTransitionEnd (leaflet-src.js:4599)
    at NewClass.fire (leaflet-src.js:593)
    at NewClass._complete (leaflet-src.js:3018)
    at NewClass._step (leaflet-src.js:2996)
    at NewClass._animate (leaflet-src.js:2985)
```

I've set up a minimal example to demonstrate this:
[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-2-map-sync-error-73iry)